# Responsive UI breaks when screen size is changed

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface, responsive-design, responsiveness

I am working on a responsive web application. The problem is that when I change the screen size, margins break, but works perfectly when the web page is refreshed. What should i do? I am using css for implementing designs and responsiveness.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: I am making a guess here. You are maintaining 2 codebases, 1 for mobile and 1 for laptop. You useState() to track the window's current size and rerender the components appropriately. Show your code and we can discuss it further.

Answer (score 1):

You need manage it to be responsive to the screen size. It's useful to see the following link:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_mediaquery_breakpoints

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   body { margin: 100px; }
}

/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
   body { margin: 20px; }
}
```